# Clicking on email address loads it as a webpage as well on webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing an app that is similar to a web browser.
Now when i click on an email address in a web page displayed thru a WebView, this is what happens :

1. A set of email clients for me to choose from are displayed
2. The webview tries to load the url, "mailto:abc@xyz.com" and displays the error page when it cannot find the url.

I am trying to figure out how to solve the problem in No.2.

Basically, i do not need the app to load the url that contains a 'mailto:'.

Here's what i have tried to do but failed:

1. under 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading()',

   ```
   if( url.startsWith("mailto") )
   {
       /*Do the stuff for sending email but i will not display */
        url = null;
   }
   ```
2. Before the view.loadurl(url),
   Added a

   ```
   if( !url.startsWith("mailto:") )
        view.loadurl(url);
   ```

I know these are hacks and are not very elegant.
Hence, can someone point me in the right path ?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you returning on `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` after you set url to null?

Comment: Hi Marcelo, it would be
return super.shoudOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with using `return true;` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method. :)

Comment: So yes, return true instead of return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view,url) solves the problem.
I will post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ravi Bhatt's answer is correct. At the end of the function, it should return true;

BUT you will have to manually capture any url containing http or https and load the url. Here's what i meant :

Under shouldOverrideUrlLoading(),

```
else if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") )
{
    view.loadUrl(url); //u can use the default webview or your own webview            
}

/*At the end of the function*/                
return true;
```

If you put in a return false somewhere, it will not work too.
url = null will not help too.

Hope this helps anyone else out there with similar problems to mine.

Comment: If my answer helped you, then you should mark it as right. Not yours by editing mine. You can put your extra words as comment with the correct answer.